# Projective Resolution of exterior algebra as a module over divided polynomial algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module, graded-modules, graded-algebras

Let $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an exterior algebra on one generator with $|x|=n$, let $\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a divided polynomial algebra with $|x_k|= kn$, and suppose that $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a module over $\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

The multiplication on $\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is given by
$$
x_kx_l = {k+l \choose k }x_{k+l}.
$$

> Question: Calculate a projective resolution for $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as a module over $\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

### Attempt

I'm attempting to answer this without any overly technical machinery (bar construction/Kozul complex etc). I will denote $\mathbb{Z}_{x_k}$ a copy of the integers generated by $x_k$.

[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I am only interested in the case up to $\mathbb{Z}_{x_4}$ as it is all I need for the calculation purposes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can continue computing a minimal free resolution as you have done.  If I haven't made a mistake, the answer, up through degree $4n$, is $\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}[x] \cdot \{\alpha_0, \beta_2, \gamma_3, \delta_4, \epsilon_3, \zeta_4, \eta_4, \theta_4\}$ where the degree of each basis element is $n$ times the subscript.  The differentials are:
\begin{align*}
d(\alpha_0) &= 1 \\
d(\beta_2) &= x_2 \alpha_0 \\
d(\gamma_3) &= x_3 \alpha_0 \\
d(\delta_4) &= x_4 \alpha_0 \\
d(\epsilon_3) &= 3\gamma_3 - x_1 \beta_2 \\
d(\zeta_4) &= 6\delta_4 - x_2 \beta_2 \\
d(\eta_4) &= 4\delta_4 - x_1 \gamma_3 \\
d(\theta_4) &= x_1 \epsilon_3 + 2\zeta_4 - 3\eta_4.
\end{align*}

Comment: What does the notation $\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}[x] \cdot \{\alpha_0, \beta_2, \gamma_3, \delta_4, \epsilon_3, \zeta_4, \eta_4, \theta_4\}$ mean? Would it be possible for you to display this in a similar fashion to how I have above

Comment: The notation just means a free $\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}[x]$ module with generators $\alpha_0, \beta_2, \ldots, \theta_4$ of the appropriate degrees.  Unfortunately, my knowledge of MathJax is not good enough to TeX up a diagram.  If it helps, $\alpha_0$ has homological degree $0$, $\beta_2, \gamma_3, \delta_4$ has degree $1$, $\epsilon_3, \zeta_4, \eta_4$ has degree $2$, and $\theta_4$ has degree $3$.